# Subscriber class android.app.Application has no public methods called onEvent

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I have delegated some of my Views from Activity to a class named BottomBar.

What I want is when I the back button to send an event to the BottomBar so an animation starts to play.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isSubMenuDisplayed) {
        isSubMenuDisplayed = false; 
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventStartReverseAnimation(true));
        //post event to fragment
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This is my code for onBackPressed() and I have onEvent in BottomBar :

```
public void onEventStartReverseAnimation(EventStartReverseAnimation event) {
    swedsFlag = event.getFlag();
    if (swedsFlag) {
        playBackAnimation(true);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse I register/unregister EventBus on Activity and then I try to register eventBus on the BottomBar class but I get the exception I have in the post title :

```
 de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: Subscriber class android.app.Application has no public methods called onEvent
```

The app crashes at the line where I register EventBus for BottomBar class :

```
    public BottomBar(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    myServiceClient = new MyServiceClient();
    myServiceClient.initializeRestClient();
    bbUtils = new BottomBarUtils(context);

    EventBus.getDefault().register(context);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have onEvent in BottomBar

No, you do not, according to that code snippet. You have `onEventStartReverseAnimation()`. Rename that method to be `onEvent()`, or `onEventMainThread()`, or one of the other supported method names.